# How to replace all string between second and third occurance of pipe character using regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to replace all the characters occurring between second and third pipe character. Example:

```
|hello|welcome,to|
```

In this I want replace `welcome,to` with a blank value, with a huge file to be replaced. I need a regex pattern to be used in notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

In notepad++ use this regex for search:

```
^([^|]*\|[^|]*\|)[^|]*
```

And replace by:

```
$1
```

`([^|]*\|[^|]*\|)` matches and captures text before 2nd `|` into a capturing group #1.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2JjwPA/3)

Comment: Notepad++ doesn't have a checkbox to switch the multiline mode, this mode is activated by default.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're parsing each line, i.e. a token cannot include a newline:

<kbd>Find what:</kbd>

```
^((?:[^|\n]*\|){2})[^|\n]*+\|
```

<kbd>Replace with:</kbd>

```
$1|
```

Description

- `^`- matches the start of line
- `((?:[^|\n]*\|){2})` - matches and captures in group 1:

  - `(?:[^|\n]*\|){2}` the following expression repeated twice
  - `[^|\n]*` - any character except a pipe or a newline
  - `\|` - followed by a pipe
- `[^|\n]*+` - the token you want to remove (any char except pipe or newline)
- `\|` - followed by a pipe